# how to create my own dialer screen in android programmatically

Tags: android, android-dialer

I want to create in my application dialer that can dial to numbers.
I tried to do something structured, but it opens up a new activity, and I need it in the tag.

This is an example I found, but not good for me:

```
Intent intent = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_CALL);
startActivity (intent);
```

What else can I do to make my Own dialer or even use something exists but not opened by the new activity.

Thank you in advance for your help!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. Maximum you can show customPopupWindow on top of the system dial screen.

Comment: ? I did not understand, what do you suggest to do

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
startActivity (intent);
```

Also, you should register the custom dialscreen as follows in the manifest:

```
<application
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name" >
<activity
    android:name=".MyDialerApplication"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >

    <intent-filter android:priority="100" >
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:scheme="tel" />

    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```